# Convert BibTex file to database entries using Python

Tags: python, mysql, bibtex

Given a bibTex file, I need to add the respective fields(author, title, journal etc.) to a table in a MySQL database (with a custom schema).

After doing some initial research, I found that there exists [Bibutils](http://sourceforge.net/p/bibutils/home/Bibutils/) which I could use to convert a bib file to xml. My initial idea was to convert it to XML and then parse the XML in python to populate a dictionary.

My main questions are:

1. Is there a better way I could do this conversion?
2. Is there a library which directly parses a bibTex and gives me the fields in python?

(I did find  [bibliography.parsing](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bibliograph.parsing/1.0.1), which uses bibutils internally but there is not much documentation on it and am finding it tough to get it to work).

Comment: Ask at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 26):

Old question, but I am doing the same thing at the moment using the [Pybtex](http://pybtex.sourceforge.net/) library, which has an inbuilt parser:

```
from pybtex.database.input import bibtex

#open a bibtex file
parser = bibtex.Parser()
bibdata = parser.parse_file("myrefs.bib")

#loop through the individual references
for bib_id in bibdata.entries:
    b = bibdata.entries[bib_id].fields
    try:
        # change these lines to create a SQL insert
        print b["title"]
        print b["journal"]
        print b["year"]
        #deal with multiple authors
        for author in bibdata.entries[bib_id].persons["author"]:
            print author.first(), author.last()
    # field may not exist for a reference
    except(KeyError):
        continue
```

Answer (score 5):

My workaround is to use bibtexparser to export relevant fields to a csv file;

```py
import bibtexparser
import pandas as pd

with open("../../bib/small.bib") as bibtex_file:
    bib_database = bibtexparser.load(bibtex_file)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(bib_database.entries)
selection = df[['doi', 'number']]
selection.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
```

And then write the csv to a table in the database, and delete the `temp.csv`.

This avoids some complication with pybtex I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64972354/how-can-i-get-pybtex-to-read-an-absent-field-as-null-instead-of-skipping-the-rec).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Python BibtexParser: https://github.com/sciunto/python-bibtexparser

Documentation: https://bibtexparser.readthedocs.org

It's very straight forward (I use it in production).

For the record, I am not the developer of this library.

Comment: The main repo is here: https://github.com/sciunto-org/python-bibtexparser.

Answer (score 2):

Converting to XML is a fine idea.

XML exists as an application-independent data format, so that you can parse it with readily-available libraries; using it as an intermediary has no particular drawbacks. In fact, you can usually import XML into a database without even going through a programming language such as Python (although the amount of Python you'd have to write for a task like this is trivial).

So far as I know, there is no direct, mature bibTeX reader for Python.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Perl package [Bib2ML (aka. Bib2HTML)](http://get-software.net/biblio/bibtex/utils/bib2ml/doc/index.html). It contains a `bib2sql` tool that generates a SQL database from a BibTeX database, with the following schema:

[image]

An alternative tool: [bibsql and bibtosql](http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/bibsql/).

Then you can feed it to your schema by writing some SQL conversion queries.

Comment: after a long time. I am really interested in these chart you did here. Please can you share with me how you created it?